# Finding the number of occurrences for rows

Tags: r

In R, I would like to find the number of occurrences for the unique rows of a data frame in the fastest way possible.

I have more than 2 million rows but the data fits in my 16GB-memory machine
table and ftable are fast but the number of unique combinations are more than they can handle so I receive an error message.

thanks

Steve

Answer (score 3):

Use `count` from the `plyr` package. It avoids combinations that do not occur in the data (contrary to table and the likes).

Comment: Nick, I didn't know this I'll look at plyr package.

Comment: It is indeed quite fast. Of course, R works in memory and if all of your data can be in the memory this is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

If the question was to get the number of unique lines:

```
sum(!duplicated(dfrm))
```

If the question was to get the unique lines themselves:

```
dfrm[!duplicated(dfrm), ]
```

If you want a table of unique combinations then consider this example with the inbuilt dataframe cars:

```
cars2 <- cars[sample(1:10, 20, replace=TRUE), ]  # to make some dups
table(apply(cars2,1,paste, sep=".", collapse="."))

# output #
10.18 10.26 10.34 11.17  4.10   4.2  7.22   7.4  8.16 
    2     3     3     3     3     1     1     2     2
```

Comment: I don't think that this brings frequencies. This brings the total number of unique rows.

Comment: I think you need to write your question more clearly - it is hard to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: wch: How can this be more clear? I wrote: "I would like to find the number of occurrences for the unique rows of a data frame in the fastest way possible."

Comment: @Steve: It isn't clear at all.  The number of occurrences of unique rows is, um, always one by definition of uniqueness.  (At least under one interpretation of your phrasing.)

Comment: Thanks everyone who understood the question and provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using SQL (here I use sqldf package). Sample data from @DWin answer.

```
#Occurences of rows
sqldf("SELECT speed, dist, COUNT(*) AS N FROM cars2 GROUP BY speed, dist")
#Some statistics of occurences ;)
sqldf("SELECT N,COUNT(N) AS Freq from 
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS N FROM cars2 GROUP BY speed,dist) 
       GROUP BY N")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
countNbOccurrences = function(leX, leGroData){
    return(sum(leX == leGroData))
}

sapply( theRow, countNbOccurrences, leGroData = fullListOfRows)
```